# Getting 500 error by sending POST request with nextjs, axios and phpmailer

Tags: next.js, axios, phpmailer

I have sendemail.js in /api, and sendemail.php in /api/php in my project.

I had to migrate from reactjs to nextjs which resulted in getting axios error: Request failed with status code 500. Code 500: ERR_BAD_RESPONSE, statusText: Internal Server Error.
data object parameter in submitRequest function works well as it wraps inside.

Here is the **sendemail.js**:

```
import {Controller, useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import Popup from "../../components/Popup";
import popupStyles from "../../components/styles/popup.module.css";
import InputField from "../../components/InputField";
import {PatternFormat} from "react-number-format";
import {Button} from "@/components/Button";
import inputStyles from "../../components/styles/inputField.module.css";
import LoadSpinner from "@/components/LoadSpinner";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AlertMessage from "@/components/AlertMessage";

export default function SendEmail({isOpened,setIsOpened}){
    const [loadSpinner,setLoadSpinner] = useState(false);
    const { register,control, handleSubmit,formState:{ errors, isValid,...rest }} = useForm();
    const [emailSent,setEmailSent] = useState(false);

    const closeAlert = (value)=>{
        setEmailSent(value);
    }

    const submitRequest = (data) => {
        setLoadSpinner(true);
        // .post("http://localhost:3000/api/php/sendemail.php", data)
        axios({
            method:'post',
            url:'/api/php/sendemail.php',
            data:data
        })
            .then(function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                setLoadSpinner(false);
                setIsOpened(false);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                //ошибка отправки
                setLoadSpinner(false);
                setIsOpened(false);
            })
            .finally(()=> {
                //
                setLoadSpinner(false);
                setIsOpened(false);
                setEmailSent(true);
            });
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(emailSent){
            let alertTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                setEmailSent(false);
            }, 4500);

            return () => {
                clearTimeout(alertTimer);
            };
        }

    },[emailSent])

    return(
        <div className="email_submitter">
            <Popup isOpened={isOpened} close={()=>{setIsOpened(!isOpened);}} children={
                <div className="email_submitter_content">
                    <img className={popupStyles.email_banner} src={"/assets/png/img-banner.png"}/>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitRequest)} className={`${inputStyles.form_group}`} style={{padding:"24px 16px"}}>
                        <div className={`${inputStyles.input_wrapper}`}>
                            <InputField label={"Full name"} type={"text"} placeholder={"Add fullname"} name="fullName" isRequired={true}
                                        {...register("fullName",{required:true,maxLength:255})}/>
                            {errors?.fullName?.type === "maxLength" && (<p className={`${inputStyles.form_error_message} text-xs`}>Character limit is more than 255 symbols</p>)}
                            {errors?.fullName?.type === "required" && (<p className={`${inputStyles.form_error_message} text-xs`}>Required field</p>)}
                        </div>

                        <div className={`${inputStyles.input_wrapper}`}>
                            <InputField label={"organization"} type={"text"} placeholder={"Type organization"} name="organization" isRequired={true}
                                        {...register("organization",{required:true,maxLength:255})}/>
                            {errors?.organization?.type === "required" && (<p className={`${inputStyles.form_error_message} text-xs`}>Required field</p>)}
                            {errors?.organization?.type === "maxLength" && (<p className={`${inputStyles.form_error_message} text-xs`}>Character limit is more than 255 symbols</p>)}
                        </div>


                        <div className={`${inputStyles.input_wrapper}`}>
                            <Controller
                                control={control}
                                rules={{required:true}}
                                name="telephoneNumber"
                                render={({field:{ref,...rest}}) =>(
                                    <PatternFormat {...rest} isClearable label="Telephone" format="+7 (###) - ### - ## - ##" mask="_" customInput={InputField} isRequired={true}
                                                   allowEmptyFormatting={false} placeholder="+7 (000) - 000 - 00 - 00" inputRef={ref}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />

                            {errors?.telephoneNumber?.type === "required" && (<p className={`${inputStyles.form_error_message} text-xs`}>Required field</p>)}
                        </div>
                        <Button text={"Submit"} type={"submit"}/>
                        {/*<Button className="button-filled button-lg" style={{alignSelf:"center"}} type={"submit"}>Submit</Button>*/}
                    </form>
                </div>
            }/>
            <LoadSpinner isOpened={loadSpinner} text={"Loading..."}/>
            <AlertMessage closeAlertMessage={closeAlert} isRevealed={emailSent} message={"Your contants have been sent successfully."}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And here goes my **sendemail.php**:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";

$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port       = ***;
$mail->Host       = "***********;
$mail->Username   = "*********";
$mail->Password   = "**********";
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';

$data =  json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$org = $data->organization;
$fullName = $data->fullName;
$phone = $data->telephoneNumber;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress("**********", "recipient-name");
$mail->SetFrom("("**********", $data->organization);

$mail->Subject = $org;

$content = "<p style=font-size:14px;>Organization: <b>$org</b> <br> FullName: <b>$fullName</b> <br> Telephone number:<b>$phone</b> </p>";

$mail->MsgHTML($content);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Error while sending Email.";
  var_dump($mail);
} else {
 echo "email sent successfully";
}
?>
```

I migrated from reactjs to nextjs which resulted in error 500 when submitting email. I tried changing relative path of endpoint to absolute which didn't work either.

Update: attached sendemail.php screenshot:
[sendemail.php #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbonj.png)

[sendemail.php #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Wig.jpg)

Comment: Either enable error output or look in your server's error logs to see the detail of the 500 error. We can't help you without that. I'd also recommend you base your code on [the examples provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples), which will avoid many of the mistakes you've made here.

Comment: @Synchro my bad, updated the post and attached the screenshots

Comment: Those are just different client-side renders of the same errors – you really need to see the source of the error on the back end. That said, I suspect that if you look at what's in the `response` property in that axios error, it might tell you something useful. Also, please post output like that as text rather than images.